# Iterate over Typescript interface keys without package?

Tags: typescript

I know this is not the first time asked, but old questions don't help.
Is there a way to get all the keys of an interface in Typescript, without, an external package?

Comment: Not at runtime, no. Unless you use a runtime construct like a `Class` instead of an interface

Comment: Nothing has changed since the old questions, so there's not much to be done here other than to mark as a duplicate.